# Как чекнуть другую радиокнопку, если определенная уже чекнута

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio2" />
    <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio3" />
    <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio4" />
    <label for="radio4">Еще текст radio кнопки №4</label>
</div>
```

как написать условие если радиокнопка с name="option" id="radio2" чекнута, то чекнуть name="anothername" с id="radio4" тоже

Comment: Радиокнопки не так работают.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
/*хватаем элемент по id  вешаем на него обработчик события change*/
document.getElementById('radio2').addEventListener('change', function() {
  /*и тут проверяем, если  данный эл  checked*/
  if (document.getElementById('radio2').checked) {
    /*выполняем действия  присваиваем  radio4 checked = true*/
    document.getElementById('radio4').checked = true;
    /*добавляем атрибут checked по просьбе из комментария*/
    document.getElementById('radio4').setAttribute('checked', 'checked');
  }
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio2" />
  <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio3" />
  <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio4" />
  <label for="radio4">Еще текст radio кнопки №4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо!!!!!!Еще такой вопрос чтобы появилась отметка в инпуте checked  что нужно сделать?

Comment: дополнил в ответе посмотри код

Comment: То, что нужно!!!!!Благодарю, Вы сделали мой день

Comment: BeFree Code, я считаю, это не правильным поступком...   Razmik Galstyan, ответил раньше меня,  его ответ тоже правильный...  если бы ты его ответ не принял,  а первым принял бы мой, я  сказал спасибо... а щас это не красиво.. не делай так больше...

Answer (score 5):

В `jquery` есть метод `is`. С его помощью определяем `check or uncheck` кнопки.
А после этого методом `prop` изменяем `check` другого `radio` кнопки.

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#radio2').change(function(event){
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
      $( "#radio4" ).prop( "checked", true );
      
      //После того как мы сделали `check` Второй радио кнопки давайте сделаем лог.
      console.log($( "#radio4" ).is(':checked'));
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="option" id="radio2" />
    <label for="radio2">radio кнопка №2</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio3" />
    <label for="radio3">Еще текст radio кнопки №3</label>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="radio" name="anothername" id="radio4" />
    <label for="radio4">Еще текст radio кнопки №4</label>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду теперь знать, выручили!

Comment: Еще такой вопрос чтобы появилась отметка в инпуте checked  что нужно сделать?

Comment: @BeFreeCode Что значит что бы появилась отметка `checked`? Когда  вставляешь атрибут то оно есть уже. Но браузеры часто в инспекте элементов это не показывают.

Comment: @BeFreeCode Вы хотели что бы у кнопки был атрибут `checked`. Не ясно это.